# Comprehensive list of Google Wave text editor clients?

Tags: eclipse, vim, ide, netbeans, google-wave

I know I'm late to the game, but 'still haven't found very many desktop-based Google Wave client text editors. Do any even exist?

Do you know of a Google Wave client plugin for Eclipse, VIM, Netbeans, or any other IDE? (Doesn't have to be a complete product...alpha is fine,...just curious if there's any progress in that direction).

Or do you know of a site other than these few sites that might have this kind of information?

Here's a list of the sites I've already looked at:

- http://wave-samples-gallery.appspot.com/
- http://wavety.com/
- http://mywavegadgets.com
- http://www.getwaveboard.com
- http://www.chaaps.com/huge-list-of-125-google-wave-robots-add-bots-and-enjoy-wave.html

**EDIT**: Not even a comment?

Comment: I am not aware of such a thing existing, sounds interesting though.

Comment: There is an effort to implement the wave protocol based on ECF: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=280347

Answer (score 1):

i currently implement a collaboration perspective which sync your current edited file with a wave using a robot and some server work. it should be available from my web site at http://www.devunity.com

Currently i support java,python,php and syntax highlighting.

Comment: Interesting idea. I didn't see much on the website. Do you have any additional info about the product?

Comment: sure, follow me on twitter @aloncarmel im posting a few screen shots every now and then.

Basically its a Installable plugin that installs a Devunity  Collaboration Perspective. the perspective plugin syncs your local file with a Wave session based on my App engine web app. i put alot of work into this with security measures and levels above the basic wave security levels. you can share your collaboration session and invite people to collaborate with you inside the wave without any hussle. very simple.

It includes syntax highlighting too. collaboration side by side.

Comment: im planning btw on releasing some of the code open source so people could help me build this amazing tool together. if your interested let me know. @aloncarmel or a@aloncarmel.me